# Unable to incorporate multiselect in a react arrow function

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble trying to add a `<Select/>` tag to my react webpage. I originally had an `<input/>` field, but I wanted to change it into a Select field which has only a certain amount of items. I'm pulling from this array that contains a list of objects because when I used the same `<Select/>` tag, it needed all the items it was going to show as an object:

```
// Array to hold the 17 options of SDG's
export const SDGOptions = [
    { value: '', label: 'Any'},
    { value: 'SDG 1: No Poverty', label: 'SDG 1: No Poverty'},
    { value: 'SDG 2: Zero Hunger', label: 'SDG 2: Zero Hunger'},
    { value: 'SDG 3: Good Health & Well Being', label: 'SDG 3: Good Health & Well Being'},
    { value: 'SDG 4: Quality Education', label: 'SDG 4: Quality Education'},
    { value: 'SDG 5: Gender Equality', label: 'SDG 5: Gender Equality'},
    { value: 'SDG 6: Clean Water & Sanitation', label: 'SDG 6: Clean Water & Sanitation'},
    { value: 'SDG 7: Affordable & Clean Energy', label: 'SDG 7: Affordable & Clean Energy'},
    { value: 'SDG 8: Decent Work & Economic Growth', label: 'SDG 8: Decent Work & Economic Growth'},
    { value: 'SDG 9: Industry, Innovation, & Infrastructure', label: 'SDG 9: Industry, Innovation, & Infrastructure'},
    { value: 'SDG 10: Reduced Inequalities', label: 'SDG 10: Reduced Inequalities'},
    { value: 'SDG 11: Sustainable Cities & Communities', label: 'SDG 11: Sustainable Cities & Communities'},
    { value: 'SDG 12: Responsible Consumption & Production', label: 'SDG 12: Responsible Consumption & Production'},
    { value: 'SDG 13: Climate Action', label: 'SDG 13: Climate Action'},
    { value: 'SDG 14: Life Below Water', label: 'SDG 14: Life Below Water'},
    { value: 'SDG 15: Life On Land', label: 'SDG 15: Life On Land'},
    { value: 'SDG 16: Peace, Justice, & Strong Institutions', label: 'SDG 16: Peace, Justice, & Strong Institutions'},
    { value: 'SDG 17: Partnerships for the Goals', label: 'SDG 17: Partnerships for the Goals'},
]
```

When I click the dropdown, everything drops down fine but when I try clicking something to select it I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at onChange (ProjectAdminForm.js:92:1)
```

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { SDGOptions } from "../FilterComponents/CategoryArrays/SdgOptions";
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown"
import Select from 'react-select';

const ProjectAdminForm = () => {
    // Adding basic info
    const [sdg, setSDG] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() // Prevents refresh of page from happening
        console.log('button clicked')

        const project = {sdg}
        console.log(project)
             
        // Sending form response to backend
        const response = await fetch('/api/projects', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(project),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        const json = await response.json
        

        // Checking for error
        if (!response.ok) {
            setError(json.error)
        }
        if (response.ok) {
            // Reset form inputs back to empty string
            setSDG('')
            
            alert('Project added!')
            console.log('new project added', json)
        }
    }

    return (
        <form className="create project-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h2 style={{"textAlign": "center"}}>Add a New Project</h2>

            <hr></hr>

            <label>Sustainable Development Goal:</label>
            {/* <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder="e.g. SDG 2: Zero Hunger"
                onChange={(e) => setSDG(e.target.value)}
                value={sdg}
                required
            /> */}
            <Select
                className="basic-single"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                placeholder="Select"
                name="color"
                onChange={(e) => setSDG(e.target.value)}
                options={SDGOptions}   
            />

            
            
            <div className="add-proj">
                <button>Add Project</button>
            </div>
            
            {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default ProjectAdminForm
```

I don't really understand why it's not working here when I was able to get it to work in a React class component. Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: `onChange={(e) => setSDG(e.value)}` try this on <Select.../>, in Select onChange return object which you have selected if its `multiSelect = true` then it will return array of object not event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the HTML select but a library called `react-select`. The `onChange` function in the `react-select` library returns the object that you've selected.

You could make the following change to make it work.

```js
<Select
  className="basic-single"
  classNamePrefix="select"
  placeholder="Select"
  name="color"
  onChange={(selection) => setSDG(selection.value)}
/>
```

Different libraries have different set of APIs. It's generally a good idea to read their [API documentation](https://react-select.com) to have more clarity.